# Can't change bridge subnet or create network on Docker

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, docker

I would like to build a small infrastructure entirely under Linux. For the LDAP and file server part I would like to set up a Docker server that will host the OpenLDAP and Owncloud containers. I would like to have a 10.10.15.0/24 network for my Docker server and its containers.
This will give :
Srv_Docker : 10.10.15.10
OpenLDAP : 10.10.15.1
Owncloud : 10.10.15.5

It is impossible to create a network with the addressing 10.10.15.0/24 because it seems that there is already a network with this addressing.
Creating a network with subnet 10.10.15.0/24

```
docker network create --subnet 10.10.15.0/24 --gateway 10.10.15.254 test
Error response from daemon: Pool overlaps with other one on this address space
```

ifconfig

```
ifconfig :
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.10.15.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 10.10.255.255
        ether 02:42:99:46:57:11  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.10.15.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.255.15.255
        inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe1d:9bc9  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:1d:9b:c9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 183  bytes 13477 (13.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 81  bytes 9002 (9.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 19  base 0x2000
```

Network listing

```
Docker network ls 
NETWORK ID     NAME      DRIVER    SCOPE
6769af814ca4   bridge    bridge    local
91992f85bf6d   host      host      local
3d8f8aeefaf6   none      null      local
```

Bridge network display

```
docker inspect bridge :
                    "Subnet": "10.10.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "10.10.15.1"
```

Display OS version

```
cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS"
```

Display docker version

```
docker version
Version:          20.10.18
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because your existing `bridge` network has a `/16` mask configuration, meaning that the available network range is from `10.10.0.1` to `10.10.255.254` so your new network belongs to that range.

You have two options

1. Delete your existing `bridge` network

```
docker network rm bridge
```

2. Create a network out of that range

```
docker network create --subnet 10.11.0.0/24 --gateway 10.11.0.254 test
```

Comment: I can't remove the bridge as it is the Docker predefined network.
I tried to create a `daemon.json` file and add the statement: `--bip "10.10.15.0/24"` but it does not change anything. The subnet of my bridge remains `10.10.0.0/16` @tachomi

Comment: @Frod0n Have you restarted the service? `sudo systemctl restart docker.service`